# Filter between two components AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, components, angularjs-filter

I know I can filter like this:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="searchTable">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.rows | filter: searchTable">
      <td>{{ row.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.lastName }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I filter if the `<input type="search" ng-model="searchTable">` and `<tr ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.rows | filter: searchTable">` are in separate components?

Here's a simple **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0ksag2g/)**.

From what I understand I'll need to add an `$onChanges()` and expression binding `bindings: { onChange: '&' }` to the `searchComponent`, but don't fully understand how to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/g0ksag2g/1/) is the working fiddle. You store the search term in parent component and pass it to both child components.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appController', function() {
 this.search = "";
});

app.component('searchComponent', {
 template: `
   <h4>{{ $ctrl.title }}</h4>
    <label>Search table</label>
    <input type="search" ng-model="$ctrl.search">
  `,
  controller: function() {
   this.title = 'Search Component';
  },
  bindings: {
   search: "="
  }
});

app.component('tableComponent', {
 template: `
   <h4>{{ $ctrl.title }}</h4>
    <!-- <p>This works</p> 
    <label>Search table</label>
    <input type="search" ng-model="searchTable"> -->
    <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.rows | filter: $ctrl.search">
         <td>{{ row.firstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
  controller: function() {
   this.title = 'Table Component';
    
    this.rows = [
     {firstName: 'Zulu', lastName: 'Apple'},
      {firstName: 'Alice', lastName: 'xRay'},
      {firstName: 'Fred', lastName: 'Rogers'}
    ];
  },
  bindings: {
   search: "<"
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <h3>Filter Between Components</h3>
    <search-component search="search"></search-component>
    <table-component search="search"></table-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **emit - on** in your component to communicate between as shown in the below code. Also please check your updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7wwt00w/) with working example of your given scenario.

**Search Component Controller:**

```
$scope.$watch('searchTable', function() {
  $rootScope.$emit('onEmitSearchData', $scope.searchTable);
});
```

**Table Component Controller:**

```
$rootScope.$on('onEmitSearchData', function(event, data) {
  $scope.searchTable = data;
});
```